# MongoDB using too much memory

Tags: mongodb, memory, wiredtiger

We've been using MongoDB for several weeks now, the overall trend that we've seen has been that mongodb is using **way too much memory** (much more than the whole size of its dataset + indexes).

I've already read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036941/mongodb-consumes-a-lot-of-memory), but none seem to address the issue I've been facing, they're actually explaining what's already explained in the documentation.

The following are the results of *htop* and *show dbs* commands.

[image]

[image: show dbs]

I know that mongodb uses memory mapped IO, so basically the OS handles caching things in the memory, and mongodb [should theoretically let go of its cached memory when another process requests free memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#id2), but from what we've seen, it doesn't.

OOM kicks in an starts killing other important processes e.g. postgres, redis, etc. (As can be seen, to overcome this problem, we've increased the RAM to 183GB which now works but is pretty expensive. mongo's using ~87GBs of ram, nearly 4X of the size of its whole dataset)

So,

1. Is this much memory usage really expected and normal ? (As per documentation, WiredTiger uses at most ~60% of RAM for its cache, but considering the dataset size, does it even have enough data to be able to take 86GBs of RAM ?)
2. Even if the memory usage is expected, why won't mongo let go of its allocated memory in case another process starts requesting for more memory ? Various other running processes were being constantly killed by linux oom, including mongodb itself, before we increased the RAM and it made the system totally unstable.

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe some of the presentations on internals of WiredTiger, such as https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/a-technical-introduction-to-wiredtiger,  can shed some light. I expect the default usage of 50% of physical RAM is just a guess at what is likely required on a dedicated MongoDB host, and many will need to change it. FWIW, I don't believe setting the cacheSizeGB is "limiting" mongo  -- the option is there so you have control over deployments. Determining how much memory mongo "needs" for cache would require you to monitor server cache statistics under expected server load.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, so after following the clues given by loicmathieu and jstell, and digging it up a little, these are the things I found out about MongoDB using WiredTiger storage engine. I'm putting it here if anyone encountered the same questions.

The memory usage threads that I mentioned, all belonged to 2012-2014, **all pre-date WiredTiger** and are describing behavior of the original MMAPV1 storage engine which doesn't have a separate cache or support for compression.

The WiredTiger [cache settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) only controls the size of memory directly used by the WiredTiger storage engine (not the total memory used by mongod). Many other things are potentially taking memory in a MongoDB/WiredTiger configuration, such as the following:

- **WiredTiger compresses disk storage, but the data in memory are uncompressed.**
- **WiredTiger by default does not fsync the data on each
  commit**, so the log files are also in RAM which takes its toll on
  memory. It's also mentioned that in order to use I/O efficiently,
  WiredTiger chunks I/O requests (cache misses) together, that also
  seems to take some RAM (In fact dirty pages (pages that has
  changed/updated) have a list of updates on them stored in a
  [Concurrent SkipList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904439/when-is-a-concurrentskiplistset-useful)).
- **WiredTiger keeps multiple versions of records in its cache** (Multi
  Version Concurrency Control, read operations access the last
  committed version before their operation).
- **WiredTiger Keeps checksums of the data in cache.**
- **MongoDB itself consumes memory to handle open connections, aggregations, serverside code and etc**.

Considering these facts, relying on `show dbs;` was not technically correct, since it only shows the compressed size of the datasets.

The following commands can be used in order to get the full dataset size.

```
db.getSiblingDB('data_server').stats()
# OR
db.stats()
```

This results is the following:

```
{
    "db" : "data_server",
    "collections" : 11,
    "objects" : 266565289,
    "avgObjSize" : 224.8413545621088,
    "dataSize" : 59934900658, # 60GBs
    "storageSize" : 22959984640,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 41,
    "indexSize" : 7757348864, # 7.7GBs
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So it seems that the actual dataset size + its indexes are taking about 68GBs of that memory.

Considering all these, I guess the memory usage is now pretty expected, good part being it's completely okay to limit the WiredTiger cache size, since it handles I/O operations pretty efficiently (as described above).

There also remains the problem of OOM, to overcome this issue, since we didn't have enough resources to take out mongodb, we lowered the **oom_score_adj** to prevent OOM from killing important processes for the time being (Meaning we told [OOM not to kill our desired processes](http://backdrift.org/oom-killer-how-to-create-oom-exclusions-in-linux)).

Comment: We've a similar issue. MongoDB keep eating up RAM. Similar proportions. Was the `oom_score_adj ` solution the best thing you manage to come up with?

Comment: @Hartator Well we decreased wiredtiger's cacheSize, put more efforts on managing our indexes and the indexing policy, and then finally, decreased oom_score_adj for things we cared for, that's I guess all that can be done anyways.

Answer (score 15):

## Docs

You may like to read [basic memory concerns for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics-for-the-wiredtiger-storage-engine) and also this [brief discussion about checking memory usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#memory-and-the-mmapv1-storage-engine).

## Memory usage overview

The command `db.serverStatus()` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/)) can provide an overview of memory usage, specifically:

```
> db.serverStatus().mem
{ "bits" : 64, "resident" : 27, "virtual" : 397, "supported" : true }

> db.serverStatus().tcmalloc
... not easy to read! ...

> db.serverStatus().tcmalloc.tcmalloc.formattedString
------------------------------------------------
MALLOC:        3416192 (    3.3 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +      4788224 (    4.6 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +       366816 (    0.3 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
...
... a bunch of stats in an easier to read format ...
```

When we had a RAM problem, it was because one of our indexes was taking up too much RAM.  So here I will show how we tracked it down.

## How big are your indexes?

`db.stats()` can show the total size of all indexes, but we can also get detailed info for a single collection using `db.myCollection.stats()`

For example, this command will **compare the sizes of the indexes for every collection**:

```
> db.getCollectionNames().map(name => ({totalIndexSize: db.getCollection(name).stats().totalIndexSize, name: name})).sort((a, b) => a.totalIndexSize - b.totalIndexSize).forEach(printjson)
...
{ "totalIndexSize" : 696320, "name" : "smallCollection" }
{ "totalIndexSize" : 135536640, "name" : "bigCollection" }
{ "totalIndexSize" : 382681088, "name" : "hugeCollection" }
{ "totalIndexSize" : 511901696, "name" : "massiveCollection" }
```

Now we can **look at the details** for that massive collection, to see which of its indexes are the most costly:

```
> db.massiveCollection.stats().indexSizes
{
        "_id_" : 230862848,
        "groupId_1_userId_1" : 49971200,
        "createTime_1" : 180301824,
        "orderId_1" : 278528,
        "userId_1" : 50155520
}
```

This can give us a better idea of where savings might be possible.

(In this case, we had an index over `createTime` which was rather huge - one entry per document - and we decided we could live without it.)

Comment: Do indexes have a big memory cost?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen It depends on the number of unique values for the field you have indexed, relative to your server's RAM. In our case, the `createTime` index was problematic because it was unique for every single document, and that collection was huge. Indexing the other fields was ok, because there were fewer unique values (the values were clustered).

Comment: So yes, large indexes are significant to memory usage because (aside from most-recent-only collections) MongoDB tries to keep [the entire index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/) in RAM (as well as the working set).

Comment: @joeytwiddle aren't fields indexed supposed to be unique for best query performance? Also, when you got rid of the index on `createTime`, how did you manage to query on that field given a datetime range?

Comment: @asgs An index doesn't have to be unique. For example, you can index by country, which makes it faster to to fetch documents with `{country: 'UK'}`, and can often make selective queries faster too.

Comment: @asgs When we stopped indexing `createTime`, we could still query it, but it was probably more costly for the DB (potentially scanning all documents). However, for the specific case of document creation time, we could query by `_id` instead of `createTime`, because Mongo's ObjectIds actually have [their creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date) hidden inside them.

Comment: yeah. _id is the best index one could get +1

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you have a problem here with MongoDB, as jstell told you MongoDB with WiredTiger will use 50% of available memory so if you increase the RAM of your server it will takes more memory.

As why it's more than the size of DB + indexes, keep in mind that WiredTiger compress the database on disk and also use snapshot logs to record document changes. So the real size of the WiredTiger is the size using show dbs * compression_ration + size of snapshot logs. So it's almost impossible to know the exact expected size.

Keep also in mind that tools like `top`, `ps`, `htop` didn't display the memory really used by the application, refere to this SOW question for details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Now, back to your issue. You have other tools running on the same host and a OOM kills them. I'm not familiar with Linux OOM but are you sure that it kills those because of MongoDB or .. just because of them (maybe it kill Postgres because Postgres took too much memory).

Anyway, as a best practice if you have a big Mongo database, don't install it in an host shared with other databases or you will have a lot of difficulties, in case there is a problem like the one you describe here, to know who really cause the issue on the host.