# What is the damage to the database if it uses high memory storage? Are there consequences for this use? Does it affect performance?

Tags: nosql

What is the damage to the database if it uses high memory storage? Are there consequences for this use? Does it affect performance?
I need to understand a lot about this problem to be able to create solutions to it

Comment: which nosql? Generally high memory usage is good for database as a in memory cache as its quicker than retrieving data of storage. If the there is swapping to disk of excessive virtual memory then that's generally bad. You need to describe problem significantly between to attempt a solution.

Comment: Presumably you've paid for your machine's memory, so using it is a good idea as @danblack says - my own **personal** rule of thumb is that if your database server is using ~ 85% of memory without (too much) swapping, you're doing OK. Having server resources sitting idle is a waste of money (IMHO). p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Verace I think that's the general consensus for all of one's database server's hardware resources too, that sitting idle is a waste of money for something generally expensive. I'm definitely with you on that point.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to danblack's point, it's generally good for your server's memory to be mostly consumed by the database system because accessing data from memory is faster than disk, but if you don't have enough memory to support your database system's workload then you can run into performance issues when it needs to pull from disk or compensate in other ways.

If you updated your question with the specific issue you're trying to solve then we can provide more specific information, but if you're just generally asking then you don't have to worry too much about this until you run into performance issues. There's a lot of other things that can equally or more likely affect performance before memory provision does.

Comment: @danblack's Thank you for the answer, but I want to write a suggestion on one of the MONGODB issues! I chose a problem that it uses high memory for data storage., is that correct?

Comment: @GheEid if your question is "does MongoDB have performance issues because it uses a lot of memory?" then I'd say no. This is by design (as most database systems are designed to heavily rely on memory) and is normal. See here for more information on how it uses that memory: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148395/mongodb-using-too-much-memory